# Subversion GUI for CentOS 7

Tags: linux, svn, version-control, centos, centos7

I'm trying to set up a CentOS 7 system for a client, and one of the things they require is a GUI client for Subversion. They need to use SVN, but do not know how to use the command line. Previously, they used RabbitVCS on CentOS 6, but that doesn't appear to work on 7. I looked at RapidSVN as well, but that hasn't been updated since 2012, and is encountering issues when installing on CentOS 7. Are there any good SVN clients out there for CentOS 7? Is there a way to get RabbitVCS working on 7?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out, there seems to be no CentOS 7 package.

You can install the generic Linux package: http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/install/manual.

Have you considered asking this question at https://superuser.com/?